# networksetup -disconnectpppoeservice not working

Tags: terminal, network

I love doing stuff on terminal, a lot. Thats how I found this command to connect to my PPP service:

```
$ networksetup -connectpppoeservice HUAWEIMobile-
```

And its works successfully to connect my PPP service. But, when I'm trying to disconnect my PPP using

```
networksetup -disconnectpppoeservice HUAWEIMobile-
```

It's not working. Is there something with my command?

Comment: stupid question, do you need root or admin privileges to do it ?

Comment: No, I don't need admin priviliges. I even tries using sudo but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I am going here on a hunch !

```
sudo networksetup -disconnectpppoeservice HUAWEIMobile-

sudo networksetup -showpppoestatus HUAWEIMobile-
```

You confirmed it says

> connected

I further assume when you activate the PPoE service it will respond with user + password request.

Since that information was not supplied it will wait for it and refuse your disconnect request.

So we can try the activate with user name and password, then do the disconnect, you can [find the appropriate command set here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/networksetup.8.html)

Comment: First command say nothing. Second command say `connected`.

Comment: Nope, I'm having this issue and it's definitely connected. All other commands work fine, just this one does nothing.